# CSS Print Media Queries - letter size vs. A4

Tags: css, printing, media-queries

I need to support print formats for both standard American 8.5x11 Letter size, as well as A4 (210mmx297mm).
I understand that we have the css `@page{size: A4;}` css property, as well as: 
`@media print {
    ...
}`

Is there a way I can simply distinguish `letter` from `A4` while building the media query, or do I need to write out the length and width manually as in this example I found for letter size (see [CSS media queries for print paper size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51813424/css-media-queries-for-print-paper-size)) :

```
     @media print and (min-height:125vw) and (max-height: 135vw)
```

Here's an example from our current `print.css` file, where I added `@page` as an experiment:

```css
@media print {
  @page {
    size: letter;
  }
  .no-print {
    display: none;
  }

  .print-break {
    page-break-after: always;
  }

  article {
    width: 8.5in;
    height: 11in;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
}
```

Any advice to handle both `letter` and `A4` print queries would be greatly appreciated.

thanks,
Bob